# C# Using iteration to calculate the lowest value in a two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration

I just started my first C# programming class (no programming experience at all) and I have to ask the user to enter in 5 days and the amount of rainfall on each of those days and store the data in a two dimensional string array named rainfallData. I then need to find the sum, average, lowest, and highest values entered all using iteration. The sum and average I have figured out, but I cannot figure out how to find the lowest and values. I know how to find the lowest and highest values in a one dimensional array but cannot figure out the iteration needed to find it in a multidimensional array.

```
string[,] rainfallData = new string[5, 2];

Console.Write("\nPlease enter a day of the week: ");
rainfallData[0, 0] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\nHow many inches of rain did you get on {0}: ", rainfallData[0, 0]);
rainfallData[0, 1] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter the next day of the week: ");
rainfallData[1, 0] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\nHow many inches of rain did you get on {0}: ", rainfallData[1, 0]);
rainfallData[1, 1] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter the next day of the week: ");
rainfallData[2, 0] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\nHow many inches of rain did you get on {0}: ", rainfallData[2, 0]);
rainfallData[2, 1] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter the next day of the week: ");
rainfallData[3, 0] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\nHow many inches of rain did you get on {0}: ", rainfallData[3, 0]);
rainfallData[3, 1] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter the next day of the week: ");
rainfallData[4, 0] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\nHow many inches of rain did you get on {0}: ", rainfallData[4, 0]);
rainfallData[4, 1] = Console.ReadLine();

double myMin2 = Convert.ToDouble(rainfallData[0, 1]);
for (int i = 0; i < rainfallData.GetLength(0); i++)
{
   foreach (double element in rainfallData[i, 1])
     {
     if (element < myMin2)
     {
       myMin2 = element;
     }
     }
}
Console.WriteLine("The day with the lowest amount of rainfall received {0}\" of rain.\n", myMin2);
```

No matter what values are entered for the rainfall, myMin2 is always the value of rainfallData[0,1]. I understand that this is because I set myMin2 = Convert.ToDouble(rainfallData[0, 1] however this same format worked when finding the lowest value of a one-dimensional array earlier in the code. The loops are throwing me for a loop and I have been stuck on this one section for 3 hours now. I wanted to find the answer on my own, but I am afraid unable to see the forest for the trees at this point and I am wasting valuable time which I am now out of.

PS - I did my best to post everything correctly, but this is my first time posting on this site and I don't know all of the rules yet. I'm sorry if I did it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you store all your data as String, and then you want to operate as Double

This is not the most efficient code, but it is close to yours, so I think you will understand it:

```
            string[,] rainfallData = new string[5, 2];

            // Load data for 5 days. All the data is stored as string
            for (int dayOfWeek = 0; dayOfWeek < 5; dayOfWeek++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a day of the week: ");
                rainfallData[dayOfWeek, 0] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine($"How many inches of rain did you get on {rainfallData[dayOfWeek, 0]}");
                rainfallData[dayOfWeek, 1] = Console.ReadLine();
            }


            // Now let's find the minimum.
            double minRain = Double.Parse(rainfallData[0, 1]);
            for (int dayOfWeek = 1; dayOfWeek < rainfallData.GetLength(0); dayOfWeek++)
            {
                // you need to convert to double, and then compare.
                double rainOnDayOfWeek = Double.Parse(rainfallData[dayOfWeek, 1]);
                if (rainOnDayOfWeek < minRain)
                {
                    minRain = rainOnDayOfWeek;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"The day with the lowest amount of rainfall received {minRain} of rain.");
```

let me know if you don't understand it

----EDIT----

It is not easy to explain just writing why your code did not work, here I try:

```
                // Here a lot of very confusing things are happening:
                // 1. All Strings are an array of characters, so here you are doing: "foreach character in rainfallData[i, 1]"
                // 2. In all programming languages, every character is also a code (number). That is called ASCII code. 
                // because you do "double element" you are asking C# to convert that character into it's code
                // for example, 'a' = 97, 'b' = 98, 'A' = 65, 'B' = 66, '1' = 49, '2' = 50
                foreach (double element in rainfallData[i, 1])
                {
                    if (element < myMin2)
                    {
                        myMin2 = element;
                    }
                }

                // This code is exactly the same as the previous one.
                // Maybe here you understand better what is going on
                foreach (char element in rainfallData[i, 1])
                {
                    // This is not the same as Convert.ToDouble, here you are getting the ASCII code of the char
                    double elementCode = (double)element; 
                    if (element < myMin2)
                    {
                        myMin2 = element;
                    }
                }
```

----EDIT 2----
Try to add this line to your code, and execute it. Maybe you can see what I meant:

`Console.WriteLine($"Element = '{element}'. In ASCII, '{element}' == '{(char)element}' and myMin2 = '{myMin2}'");`

```
            double myMin2 = Convert.ToDouble(rainfallData[0, 1]);
            for (int i = 0; i < rainfallData.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                foreach (double element in rainfallData[i, 1])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Element = '{element}'. In ASCII, '{element}' == '{(char)element}' and myMin2 = '{myMin2}'");
                    if (element < myMin2)
                    {
                        myMin2 = element;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: First off, thank you! I am still very new to C#, but what is the difference between Convert.ToDouble and the Double.Parse that you used?

Comment: You are welcome! For your case there are no differences. But for future reference there are some differences: For example, Double.Parse allows you to specify what is the culture (for instance, if the decimal symbol is a dot or a comma)

Comment: I marked it as answered.

I wasn't aware that you could populate the elements of an array the way you did it. I guess we haven't quite gotten that far yet - this is only the 3rd program we've had to write.

That being said, the assignment says to create a string array, ask the user to input the days of the week and the rainfall for each day, and then do a number of things w/ the array once created (sum, average, find lowest, find highest).

I was using Convert.ToDouble while you used Double.Parse to convert the string into a double. Is this where I was running into trouble?

Comment: No, the problem is that you don't need the foreach. Instead you need to convert to double the value in rainfallData[i, 1]. I edited the answer to try to explain a bit more what is the problem with your code. Every time I used Double.Parse you can use Convert.ToDouble and it will work fine, that was not the issue with your code

Answer (score 0):

```
string[,] rainfallData = new string[5, 2];
        int b = 0;
        int lowest = 99,highest=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <rainfallData.Length-5; i++)
        {

            for (b = 0; b < 1; b++)
            {

                if (i != rainfallData.Length)
                {
                    Console.Write("Please enter a day of the week: ");
                    rainfallData[i, b] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("How many inches of rain did you get on {0}: ", rainfallData[i, b]);
                    rainfallData[i, b] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                    break;

            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rainfallData.Length-5; i++)
        {
            for (b = 0; b<1; b++)
            {
                lowest = Math.Min(lowest, Convert.ToInt32(rainfallData[i, b]));
                highest = Math.Max(highest, Convert.ToInt32(rainfallData[i, b]));

            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("The day with the lowest amount of rainfall received {0}\" of rain.", lowest);
        Console.WriteLine("The day with the highest amount of rainfall received {0}\" of rain.", highest);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Victor. You are comparing the day of the week with the amount of rain.. For example rainfallData[0] = "Wednesday" and rainfallData[1] = 14.8 .... if you remove the second nested for then your code works perfectly :)

Comment: Thanks for the clearance Carlos.Its only now that I notice.